# Converting time format to second in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a df with time data and I would like to transform these data to second (see example below).

```
 Compression_level Size (M) Real time (s) User time (s) Sys time (s)
0                  0      265      0:19.938      0:24.649      0:3.062
1                  1       76      0:17.910      0:25.929      0:3.098
2                  2       74      1:02.619      0:27.724      0:3.014
3                  3       73      0:20.607      0:27.937      0:3.193
4                  4       67      0:19.598      0:28.853      0:2.925
5                  5       67      0:21.032      0:30.119      0:3.206
6                  6       66      0:27.013      0:31.462      0:3.106
7                  7       65      0:27.337      0:36.226      0:3.060
8                  8       64      0:37.651      0:47.246      0:2.933
9                  9       64      0:59.241       1:8.333      0:3.027
```

This is the output I would like to obtain.

```
df["Real time (s)"]
0    19.938
1    17.910
2    62.619
...
```

I have some useful code but I do not how to itinerate this code in a data frame

```
x = time.strptime("00:01:00","%H:%M:%S")
datetime.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour,minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `00:` from right side for `0hours`, pass to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then add [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df["Real time (s)"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Real time (s)"].radd('00:')).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
   Compression_level  Size (M)  Real time (s) User time (s) Sys time (s)
0                  0       265         19.938      0:24.649      0:3.062
1                  1        76         17.910      0:25.929      0:3.098
2                  2        74         62.619      0:27.724      0:3.014
3                  3        73         20.607      0:27.937      0:3.193
4                  4        67         19.598      0:28.853      0:2.925
5                  5        67         21.032      0:30.119      0:3.206
6                  6        66         27.013      0:31.462      0:3.106
7                  7        65         27.337      0:36.226      0:3.060
8                  8        64         37.651      0:47.246      0:2.933
9                  9        64         59.241       1:8.333      0:3.027
```

Solution for processing multiple columns:

```
def to_td(x):
    return pd.to_timedelta(x.radd('00:')).dt.total_seconds()

cols = ["Real time (s)", "User time (s)", "Sys time (s)"]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(to_td)
print (df)
   Compression_level  Size (M)  Real time (s)  User time (s)  Sys time (s)
0                  0       265         19.938         24.649         3.062
1                  1        76         17.910         25.929         3.098
2                  2        74         62.619         27.724         3.014
3                  3        73         20.607         27.937         3.193
4                  4        67         19.598         28.853         2.925
5                  5        67         21.032         30.119         3.206
6                  6        66         27.013         31.462         3.106
7                  7        65         27.337         36.226         3.060
8                  8        64         37.651         47.246         2.933
9                  9        64         59.241         68.333         3.027
```